# Why can't I implement abstract method as private method

Tags: java

With the abstract class

```
abstract class A {
    abstract int getInt();
}
```

and the implementation

```
public class AImp extends A{
    @Override
    private int getInt() {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

I get the error that I can't give the method less access privileges than it already had. I want to implement the abstract method as a private method. I understand why I can't define the abstract method in `A` and `private abstract`, because that would make it impossible for the implementation to see the method, BUT why can the implementation not simply make the abstract method private?

**RATIONALE:**

I have two classes with an identical method which depends on a private method:

```
public class AImp1{
    private int getInt() {
        return 1;
    }
    protected void print10Int() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            System.out.println(getInt());
        }
    }
}

public class AImp2{
    private int getInt() {
        return 0;
    }
    protected void processInt() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            System.out.println(getInt());
        }
    }
}
```

In order to avoid code repetition, I want to put that method in an abstract superclass, but that forces me to make the private method part of the abstract superclass too:

```
abstract class A {
    abstract int getInt();

    protected void print10Int() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            System.out.println(getInt());
        }
    }
}
```

Since I want the same `AImp1` and `AImp2` as before, I want to make `getInt` private:

```
public class AImp1 extends A{
    @Override
    private int getInt() {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

which is what causes the error.

Comment: Why do you want to implement it in a private method? What's the reason?

Comment: If you make it private it can't be seen and thus it can't be called from the outside even though the abstract superclass says so

Comment: I didn't know you can't - never tried it. But it makes absolutely no sense to declare something that needs to be overwritten(abstract needs an implementation) but can't because private methods by definition can't. And changing something pakage private to private in a sub  defeats the private due to assignability to the super.

Comment: you are changing the behaviour/signature of the method, just like overriding it and returning a double instead. Simply illegal

Comment: Why do you want to make it private? So that child classes of `AImp` cannot override it? In which case, make it final.

Comment: You have to understand first why an `abstract` method was needed in the first place. Clearly in abstract method you are not providing implementation in the method body but you chose to leave the method name along with signature in there for a reason. By doing that you are implying that any class that is going to extend my abstract class should handle the implementation of this `abstract` method. It is an implicit contract. Now you want that class to be able to access this `abstract` method. You have to either make it `protected` or `public`.

Comment: It was an arbitrary decision by Sun all those years ago to prohibit abstract methods being private. If private abstract methods were allowed, we would be allowed to override them with private methods too. It works well in other languages (such as C++).

Comment: @ernest_k: I have added my reason for wanting to do this in an edit

Comment: just let the subclass provide the `int` via the constructor, no need for an `abstract` method: `public abstract class A { private final int i; protected A(int i) { this.i = i; }`

Comment: @Sahand I see. You can't unfortunately make it private. Just make it `protected`, unless all classes are in the same package, in which case you can make it package-scoped

Comment: @Lino, unfortunately the `getInt`-method is just a simplification. The real behaviour is more complicated and cannot be moved to the constructor.

Comment: @Sahand you could make use of functional interfaces `protected A(IntSupplier getInt){this.getInt = getInt; }` and then the subclass could provide lambda in the constructor: `super(() -> /* some computation which yields an int */);`

Comment: The Template Method design pattern is one example where private abstract methods (and private overriding methods) would have been useful. Having to make them protected or package-private exposes too much implementation detail (i.e. it reduces encapsulation). C++ allows abstract methods to be private; Java has this unfortunate restriction.

Comment: If super class has a method as `public` then each sub class already has it as `public`, this is due to polymorphism. Suppose a case `Parent obj = new Child();` now if there is any abstract or non abstract method that is there in `Parent` class, it can be invoked on `obj`. Trying to Mak e it `private` in child is of no use and it is misleading hence Java language better decided it to be a compile time error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it's used as part of a class' signature/interface. Say I know that children of class A will have method Foo(), but when I try to access Foo() of class B that extends class A, I cannot because it's private. It makes no sense.

Comment: Yeah, but if the abstract method itself was private... Unfortunately, that's not allowed in Java.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException I read now that [Java 9+ allows](https://www.journaldev.com/12850/java-9-private-methods-interfaces) interfaces to declare private methods.

Comment: That's true, but it's not related to this issue. Private methods in interfaces are only accessible to default methods in the same interface. They can't be overridden. In other languages, such as C++, abstract methods can be private and can therefore be overridden by private methods.